# Find the missing records in a SQL table based on Order Number

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, custom-list, sql-server

I have a custom database which stores Orders details in Order table.

I have a SharePoint list which stores same Orders details as well.

I would like to,

1. get Order number from SharePoint List and Query SQL table 'Order' to get the total count of missing records from database (Order table).
2. Insert data from SharePoint list to Order table in DB, if record doesn't exist in DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If coding is a option, then you can write console application using CSOM/SSOM to perform below steps:

1. Get all items from SharePoint list
2. Iterate through all items and check whether record exist in database.
3. If it doesn't exist, insert record in database.